# SQL Server - transfer Excel file with T sql

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql

Can I transfer an Excel file from one folder to another
after reading it?

let's say I have the Excel file first in "incoming" folder and
after reading it I want to transfer the file to "reads" folder

this is possible with T sql?

Comment: if you really want to avoid SSIS this article might help you out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using SSIS to accomplish this task. It has an inbuilt File System task which you can use to rename the file into another folder.